# Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) -> Excel

Tags: python, encoding, export-to-excel

I am trying to wrap my head around this for a while now and have not yet seen any solution that does not confuse me.

I got a script in python that should write an array with words (German Names) into an excel file.

```
cell = [name_1, name_2, name_3]   

import csv
 fl = open('company_data.csv', 'w')

 writer = csv.writer(fl)
 writer.writerow(['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3']) 
 for values in cell:
     writer.writerow(values)

 fl.close()
```

The error that comes is
...,line 135, in 
    writer.writerow(values)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.2s with exit code 1]

The names include the German characters ü,ä,ö etc.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's nearly a year, but have you tried using `python3` explicitly instead of `python` only? Had the same problem, had a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` everything worked fine.
If you're not on *nix, use `python3 myfile.py` and not `python myfile.py` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to open the file and specify that you want to write unicode. Aussming you want utf-8:

```
import codecs
fl = codecs.open("company_data.csv", "w", "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I still get the message: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). Does this info help to find a solution and if so how does the solution look like?